# Tikz plot smooth lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

How can I reproduce the line inside the red circle of the image above?
[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees, decorations.text,arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing, pgfplots.fillbetween, quotes, patterns.meta,shapes.geometric, decorations.markings, calc}

\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-latex,ultra thick] (-4,0)--(5,0);
        \draw[thick, dashed] (0,-4)--(0,4);
        \draw[thick, dashed] (4,-4)--(4,4);
        \draw[-latex,ultra thick] (-4,-4)--(-4,4);
        \draw[latex-latex,ultra thick] (0,3.5)--(4,3.5);
        \draw[latex-latex,ultra thick] (0,-3.5)--(-4,-3.5);    
        \node[font=\sffamily] at (2,3.8) {Generator mode};
        \node[font=\sffamily] at (-2,-3.8) {Motor mode};
        \node[] at (4.8,0.5) {Slip};
        \node[] at (-3.75,-0.3) {$1$};
        \node[] at (0.25,-0.3) {$0$};
        \node[] at (4.3,-0.3) {$-1$};
        \node[rotate = 90] at (-4.5,0) {Torque [N.m]};
        \draw[smooth, red, ultra thick] (-4,3) -- (-1.5,2.75) -- (0,2.5);
        \draw[smooth, green, ultra thick] (0,2.5) -- (0,-2.5);
        \draw[smooth, red, ultra thick] (0,-2.5) -- (1.5,-2.75) -- (4,-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You mean, the dashed ellipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to replace this:

```
\draw[smooth, red, ultra thick] (-4,3) -- (-1.5,2.75) -- (0,2.5);
```

with this:

```
\draw[smooth, red, ultra thick] plot coordinates {(-4,3) (-1.5,2.75) (0,2.5)};
```

You can also have more control with the tension parameter:

```
\draw[smooth, tension=1, red, ultra thick] plot coordinates {(-4,3) (-1.5,2.75) (0,2.5)};
```

You can play with it to see what fits you (0 will result in sharp lines like before)

The only problem is that there won't be a nice transition between the different lines

Edit: I've just found a much better solution:

```
\draw[red,ultra thick,looseness=0.3] (-4,3) to[out=0, in=90] (0,2.5);
\draw[red,ultra thick,looseness=0.3] (0,-2.5) to[out=-90,in=180] (4,-3);
```

This one allows for a much better transition to the green line, and you don't have to provide secondary points. The in and out parameters control the entry and exit angles of the curve. The looseness option has the same effect as the tension parameter in the previous solution.

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you're looking for?

[image: dashed ellipses]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees, decorations.text,arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing, quotes, patterns.meta,shapes.geometric, decorations.markings, calc}

\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-latex,ultra thick] (-4,0)--(5,0);
        \draw[thick, dashed] (0,-4)--(0,4);
        \draw[thick, dashed] (4,-4)--(4,4);
        \draw[-latex,ultra thick] (-4,-4)--(-4,4);
        \draw[latex-latex,ultra thick] (0,3.5)--(4,3.5);
        \draw[latex-latex,ultra thick] (0,-3.5)--(-4,-3.5);    
        \node[font=\sffamily] at (2,3.8) {Generator mode};
        \node[font=\sffamily] at (-2,-3.8) {Motor mode};
        \node[] at (4.8,0.5) {Slip};
        \node[] at (-3.75,-0.3) {$1$};
        \node[] at (0.25,-0.3) {$0$};
        \node[] at (4.3,-0.3) {$-1$};
        \node[rotate = 90] at (-4.5,0) {Torque [N.m]};
        \draw[smooth, red, ultra thick] (-4,3) -- (-1.5,2.75) -- (0,2.5);
        \draw[smooth, green, ultra thick] (0,2.5) -- (0,-2.5);
        \draw[smooth, red, ultra thick] (0,-2.5) -- (1.5,-2.75) -- (4,-3);
        
        \draw[densely dashed] (-2,2.8) ellipse (1.9cm and .3cm);
        \draw[densely dashed] (0,0) ellipse (0.2cm and 3cm);
        \draw[densely dashed] (2,-2.8) ellipse (1.9cm and .3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I'm looking for the plot curve, not the ellipse... I want to make the red line like in the original plot...

Comment: @FábioGregório: You already have the line in your plot! So maybe you are not happy about it? Your red circle obscures any features the line may have and you do not write anything about what you wish.

Comment: @kpekristiansen I'm sorry for the misunderstood. Yes, I wanna know about to making the red line more true to the line of the first figure...